# jquery post data not visible in PHP with codeigniter framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Hi I am using below jquery for sending post request to my PHP controller in codeigniter but when i pass the value from controller to model as an argument what i see is that the results by query is empty there with the value passed, but query works fine directly in mysql.

So the issue is after getting the value in controller when I pass it to my model as an argument and pass that value in a query no results come up but should come.

My javascript function which gets called on document load:

```
function stockUpdate(symbol)
{
    $.post("stock/stock_update",
    {
        symbol: symbol
    },
    function success(data)
    {
        alert(data);
    }
  });
}
```

My PHP controller:

```
class Stock extends CI_Controller {
    function stock_update()
    {
        // get symbol
        $symbol = $this->input->post('symbol');

        // get the price for symbol and calculate unit price
        $result = $this->user_stock_model->get_price($symbol);
        print_r($result); // nothing gets printed
    }
}
```

My user_stock_model:

```
class User_stock_model extends CI_Model {
    public function get_price($symbol)
    {
        // get user id
        $id = $this->session->userdata('id');

        echo $symbol; // value gets printed

        // fetch total price where symbol as given
        $sql = "SELECT shares, price FROM users_stock ".
               "WHERE id = ? and symbol = ?";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($id, $symbol));
        return $query->row_array(); // empty results
    }
}
```

As the symbol variable contains no value in this function which results in empty results from my query.

One more thing I would like to tell that if I run the exact same jquery script from Chrome developer tools console it works absolutely fine.

Comment: As an aside, consider using $symbol = $this->input->post('symbol') instead of $symbol = $_POST['symbol']; It pre-processes global input data for security.

Comment: @Drazion Actually I thought might be that is creating a problem so I did native $_POST. Will fix that as i found out the issue now, as given in my answer. I was dumb..Silly isuue. What I learnt is Never underestimate a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the value sent by the jquery post request to my controller is prepended and appended with spaces. And while printing it directly value seems fine but query returns no results.

For example:

what I see as: 'A'

was actually: ' A '

Thus when i put echo statements in codeigniter's query function the query formed was:

```
SELECT shares, price FROM users_stock WHERE id = '11' and symbol = ' A '
```

As there was no record in my mysql table where symbol column = ' A ', thus nothing got returned and I thought value is not visible there. My bad.

Simple PHP trim() function resolves the issue as below:

```
// get symbol
$symbol = trim($this->input->post('symbol'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the variable 'symbol' is not set before sending the request(i.e., at document.ready). Did you try logging 'symbol' before $.post?

Comment: actually I found out the problem now will post the answer right away, I did a silly mistake. My Bad